# Matlab Camera Calibration Toolbox: go_calib_optim error

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, camera-calibration, matlab-cvst, calibration

When I run go_calib_optim on the calibration data I get:

```
Error using  - 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
Error in compute_extrinsic_init (line 66)
Y = X_kk - (X_mean*ones(1,Np));
Error in comp_ext_calib (line 22)
            [omckk,Tckk] = compute_extrinsic_init(x_kk,X_kk,fc,cc,kc,alpha_c);
Error in go_calib_optim_iter (line 293)
comp_ext_calib;
Error in go_calib_optim (line 56)
go_calib_optim_iter;
Error in calibration_script (line 176)
go_calib_optim;
```

What could be causing this? Alternatively, is this routine optional? It says it is the main optimization routine but how essential is it? I can afford minor to medium errors in the calibration data.

Comment: The error is pretty clear.  At line 66 in `compute_extrinsic_init`, `X_kk` and `X_mean*ones(1,Np)` have incompatible dimensions.  Can you tell us what the size of `X_kk` and `X_mean` are?

Comment: @Booley, try the Camera Calibrator app in the Computer Vision System Toolbox: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/single-camera-calibrator-app.html